# DropwizardAppRule and maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: java, dropwizard, maven-failsafe-plugin

This is my `DropwizardAppRule` in MyAppIT.java class:

```
@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardAppRule<MyConfiguration> RULE =
        new DropwizardAppRule<>(MyApplication.class, YAML_PATH);
```

This would return the `LocalPort` my local Dropwizard App is running on:

```
RULE.getLocalPort()
```

When running in `IntelliJ`, it returns `9998` and all tests pass but when I do `mvn clean install` or `mvn verify` from the command line, it throws a `NullPointerException` and I see a bunch of `Connection refused` errors.

```
ERROR! javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Here is my `maven-failsafe-plugin` config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>MyAppIT.java</include>
        </includes>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>test.environment</name>
                <value>${test.environment}</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It seems as if the `DropwizardAppRule` isn't even starting (since the port is null). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included MyAppIT.java to the `maven-surefire-plugin` and it worked:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>MyAppIT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```